# Shopify unique product information

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

I'm new to Shopify and liquid (I have programming background). What i'm currently trying to achieve is adding some **unique** custom information in a HTML div into the product layout.

**My approach:** Because I couldn't directly edit the **product.liquid** file (was generating the same information for all products), I decided to make a hack, so I created liquid files into the snippets by joining the product id + product. The filename would look like "**11598995151product.liquid**".

Into the product.liquid, I then added the following:

```
  {% if product.description %}<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 visible-xl" style="display:block !important">
      {% assign z = x | append: product.id | append: "product" %}
      {% include z %}
  </div>{% endif %}
```

Is this the best practice or can it be done easier ?

Comment: I think you are over thinking it. I'm finding it hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, I am certain however that there is a better way of achieving the desired effect. What custom information are you trying to add to the product page. Why is it that you can't directly edit the product.liquid, I think we need some more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly confused, you can't directly update the `product.liquid` but yet you are adding an include there. So can you or you can't?

Here a few approaches how can you add custom unique information to products.

1) Use an metafeild application such as https://apps.shopify.com/metafields-editor where you can set fields for each product

2) Use shortcodes for example with this snippet https://github.com/culturekings/shopify-shortcodes

3) Create prefixed pages, for example you have a product with a handle `test-1`, and you will have a page with a handle `product-test-1`. You perform a check for each product if there is such a page.

4) Similiar to 3 but use a global navigation that will point to page, so that you don't have to prefix each one.

5) Use sections. Create blocks with a product field and a richtext field (or the information you need) and set the product and information for each product as blocks. Then on the product page you check if this product handle is equal to any of the block product field.

All of the above examples require you to modify the `product.liquid` page if you like for it to be unique for each product.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used the first approach and managed to make it work.

To clarify your confusion: I can open the product.liquid, but it was displaying the same information on every product page because of the wrong logic.

Now I use a for and loop through the metafields for each product in order to display them.